# Can I control a 12V motor from arduino using an H-bridge?

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, dc-motor, h-bridge

I want to control my 12 volt geared DC motor from my Arduino Uno. I want it to be able to rotate both directions as I'm intending to use it for a robot.
    Can I use the L293NE H-bridge in this case? The following diagram shows the pin connections. For this I'll have to externally supply the IC with 12 volts, but will I be exceeding the maximum voltage rating for the IC? I dont really want to blow up the IC in the midst of all that circuitry. Please tell me if there's a more suitable h-bridge for handling 12-volts, or another approach to my problem.

[image]

Comment: You don't give the current the motor requires, and that is what will determine whether it is suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question whether you will damage the L293NE IC, no you wont damage it if you provide 12V. Take a look in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf), there is a section stating the recommended values for each pin. So pin 8 which is the one you will be powering your motors off, can take up to 36V.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, yours is a very common application.  That chip has two power pins.  Pin 16 is for the logic level, which you would supply with 5 volts.  Pin 8 is the positive supply for the motor drivers, which you would put 12 volts on.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a mosfet. A mosfet allows low amp controllers such as a processor to activate/deactive high amp circuits, such as a large stepper motor.

Comment: A singe MOSFET will not be able to rotate the motor in both directions.